# [UIView(CALayer Delegate) drawLayer:inContext: crash

Tags: ios, crash

my app crash in [UIView(CALayer Delegate) drawLayer:inContext: ,the most difficult is there are not any code of my app in the crash log and i cannot reproduce it .This issue cost me several days and I still have no idea. Any ideas you guys provide, I will try. Thank you for your help.

```
 crash log:
    0  libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend_stret (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 18
    1  UIKit             -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:]
    2  QuartzCore         -[CALayer drawInContext:] (in QuartzCore) + 116
    3  QuartzCore          CABackingStoreUpdate_ (in QuartzCore) + 1782
    4  QuartzCore          CA::Layer::display_() (in QuartzCore) + 972
    5  QuartzCore        CA::Layer::display() (in QuartzCore) + 128
    6  QuartzCore      CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore)
    7  QuartzCore     CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
    8  QuartzCore      CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore) + 314
    9  QuartzCore      CA::Transaction::pop() (in QuartzCore) + 126
    10 QuartzCore     +[CATransaction commit] (in QuartzCore) + 34
    11 UIKit          _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder (in UIKit) + 188
    12 UIKit           +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsForAppResume] (in UIKit) + 10
    13 UIKit          -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] (in UIKit) + 74
    14 UIKit              -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] (in UIKit) + 1080
    15 UIKit              -[UIApplication sendEvent:] (in UIKit) + 54
    16 UIKit               _UIApplicationHandleEvent (in UIKit) + 5808
```

Comment: Try tracing this with NSZombieEnabled

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the try and sectionalize the problem. Assuming you have one view that is causing this, then the most likely explanation is that something in the view is corrupt or has been released.

1) Did you try turning on Zombies, to see if some dealloc'd item is getting messaged?

2) In the view that is showing (or about to show) when the crash starts, either remove items one at a time, or remove them all from the view, and start adding them one by one. A good way to do this type of messy works is just copy your project folder, save the old one, and go cut chunks of code out so you can get to a working point.

My guess is that something is getting released before it should.